# PHP Test script works, same code in other script doesn´t

Tags: php

I´m currently trying to set up a dynamic banner to make our teamspeak server a little more fancy by displaying online clients, time and date and similar. I´ve written a little script doing the crucial connection stuff, but once I try to display the image it won´t work.

So I have decided to test the code which doesn´t seem to work in a different script, getting it to work closely to the way I want, but still the original script with the ehanced code wouldn´t work.

This is the test file:

```
<?php

header("Content-type:image/png");

        $font = "C:\Windows\Fonts\junebug.ttf"; //'junebug.TTF';
        $text1 = "It worked";
        $image = imagecreatefrompng('banner.png');

        $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

        imagettftext($image, 12, 0, 100, 100, $white, $font, $text1);

        imagepng($image);
        imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Generating the following output: [Test Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs6Fw.jpg)

This is the main script I was intentionally working on:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
include("ts3admin.class.php");



$datum = date("d.m.Y");
$uhrzeit = date("H:i");
$cslots = 0;
$maxslots = 0;

function ts3connect(){
    include("connect.php");
    $ts3 = new ts3admin( $ts3server, $ts3qport);
    $connecting = $ts3->connect();

    if($connecting["success"]){

        $selected = $ts3->selectServer($ts3port, 'port',true);

        if($selected["success"]){

            if($ts3user != "" && $ts3pass != ""){
                $login = $ts3->login($ts3user, $ts3pass);
                return $ts3;
            }
            return $ts3;
        }       
    } else {        
        return false;
    }
}

if($ts3 = ts3connect()){
    $sinfo = $ts3->serverInfo();
    if($sinfo["success"]){
        $font = "C:\Windows\Fonts\junebug.ttf"; //'junebug.TTF';
        $text1 = "It worked";
        $image = imagecreatefrompng('banner.png');

        $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

        imagettftext($image, 12, 0, 100, 100, $white, $font, $text1);

        imagepng($image);
        imagedestroy($image);
    }else{
        echo"<pre>Fehler 1: ServerInfo couldn´t be retrieved:<br><hr><br>";
        print_r($ts3);
        echo"</pre>";
    }
}else{
    echo"<pre>Fehler 2: Connecting failed:<br><hr><br>";
    print_r($ts3);
    echo"</pre>";
}

?>
```

Which resulted in an error saying something like "The graphic couldn´t be displayed because it contains errors" [Main Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oDw4.jpg)

Thank your very much in advance!

Comment: This usually happens when there's stray output from a script. Can you check the raw response using the Network pane of your devtools? You could also save the image and open it using a text editor.

Comment: Check for extra white space and HTML in the files that are `include`d too.

Comment: I got it working by looking into the logs (which I didn´t knew existed, Thank you!), and the error was in a very different file.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by looking into the errors.log file in the apache folder.

> Tip by @msg (user:4782169)

It said there was an error on line 3245 of the ts3admin.class.php

```
private function loadQueryData()
    {
        $whoAmI = $this->getElement('data', $this->whoAmI());
        $this->runtime['bot_name'] = $whoAmI['client_nickname'];

        $clients = $this->clientList();
        foreach((array)$clients['data'] as $client)   //<-- This one
        {
            if(strstr($this->runtime['bot_name'], $client['client_nickname']))
            {
                $this->runtime['bot_clid'] = $client['clid'];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

By adding the "(array)" you force the code to convert the $clients variable into an array.